# key holding wrong kind of value in redis when pushing data on a list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am trying redis on my heroku app.  I have the following code in `config/initializers/redis.rb`

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"])
REDIS = Redis.new(:host => uri.host, :port => uri.port, :password => uri.password)
```

I'm trying the following in the console but getting error:

```
irb(main):003:0> REDIS.rpush ('foo','bar')
(irb):3: warning: don't put space before argument parentheses
RuntimeError: -ERR Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error is returned when you try to operate on for instance a list value, while the key is holding another type of value (e.g. string, set, etc.). To find out what type of value is stored at `foo`, you can use the following command:

```
REDIS.type("foo")
```

When you do an `RPUSH` or `LPUSH` against a key that doesn't hold a value, a list will automatically be created. So, you have to make sure `foo` doesn't exist or holds a list value for this operation to work.